# Why C++ standard allows declaring a pointer to a class member of non-existing type?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I wonder why the language allows declaring a pointer to a member function/data although that member type doesn't exist and as we know that at compile-time, the static type must be know and the type must be full type before usage of that type apart from using an incomplete type in so restricted situations.

Here is my example:

```
struct Foo{
    int bar(bool, bool){std::cout << "Foo::bar\n"; return x_;}
    int x_ = 10;
    void do_it()const{cout << "do_it()\n";}
    void do_it(int, bool)const{cout << "do_it(int, bool)\n";};

};


int main(){
    int (Foo::* pMemBar)(bool, bool) = &Foo::bar; // ok
    (Foo{}.*pMemBar)(0, 0); // ok

    int Foo::*pMemX = &Foo::x_;
    std::cout << Foo{}.*pMemX << '\n';


    std::string (Foo::* pMemFn)(char)const; // why this is allowed?
    std::string Foo::* pMemDt = nullptr; // why allowed
}
```

- As you can see everything is OK until the declaration of pointer `pMemFn`, that pointer is a pointer to a member function of class `Foo` that is `const` and takes a single argument as`char` and returns an `std::string`. But there is no such version in the class `Foo` and as we know the compiler do knows all the members of a class so why it allows that? I know this pointer is not yet de-referenced thus there is no object of that class in such declaration and the compiler complains only when de-referencing it using a object of that type `class Foo` but why the compiler allows such declaration?

I think it would be more suitable for the compiler to refuse such declarations at the first place as it do for the static type of a pointer to a base class. What do you think? And is there a philosophy behind allowing that? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe so you can use that 'generic' pointer to point to functions in classes derived from `Foo`?

Comment: @AdrianMole: I think it is not possible because we are explicitly requesting that version or type from the class `Foo` so it is not possible to exist in derived classes but not in he base. I think this is the same way as `virtual member functions`. They must exist in the base class and can be overriden in the derived ones.

Comment: It's fine to declare a pointer that cannot point to anything due to various externalities. For example, `struct S {S() = delete; }; S* p = nullptr;` You can still declare a pointer to a non-constructible type. The only valid value for it is `nullptr`, but the pointer type is still legal. Another example of "Letting you declare things for which no valid value exists" is the infamous [abominable function](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html).

Answer (score 6):

Well first of all, you are allowed to declare pointer-to-member of class `X` before class `X` is defined (*i.e.,* only a forward declaration of `X` has been seen). So in those cases, the compiler isn't yet able to determine that there exists no member of `X` with the appropriate type.

Beyond that, there are reasons why such pointer-to-member types are needed despite the fact that there is no actual member of that type. First, `static_cast` can be done both up and down the class hierarchy: in other words, let's say we have

```
struct Bar : Foo {
    std::string s;
};
```

Now, an implicit conversion always exists from `T Foo::*` to `T Bar::*` since this is a safe conversion: if a `T Foo::*` value denotes a particular member of `Foo`, then any `Bar` object has such a member as well. When you use `static_cast`, it is possible to go the other way around: converting from `T Bar::*` to `T Foo::*`. You might wonder why one would ever want to do this. Well, it's not terribly common, but the idea is that just like how `Foo*` can point to any object derived from `Foo` (thus providing a *common type* with which to refer to such objects, enabling runtime polymorphism), `T Foo::*` also can point to any member of type `T` of any class derived from `Foo`. But you have to exercise caution, since *using* such a pointer requires knowledge that the member it denotes actually exists in the object pointed to.

Anyway, while (again) it's not terribly common, the point is that the compiler can't reject a `std::string Foo::*` because, for all it knows, there might be a class derived from `Foo` (possibly in another translation unit) that actually contains a `std::string` member.

Also, it's possible to `reinterpret_cast` between pointers to members of unrelated classes and unrelated member types. The rule is that `T X::*` can always be cast to `U Y::*` as long as `T` and `U` are both object types or both function types, except that you can't cast away constness this way (but you *can* do so with an additional `const_cast`). So I can do this for example:

```
struct Unused {};
using ObjType = int;
using FuncType = void();
```

And I can use `ObjType Unused::*` to hold pointers to *any* object type of *any* class; and I can use `FuncType Unused::*` to hold pointers to *any* function type of *any* class. But such pointers must be cast back to their original types before they can be used.

Comment: Great answer Brian. C++ is a mad language - it's been 20 years since I used it,but I see it seems to have retained its , eh, gnarlieness :-)